# Changing specific word in a file with Bash

Tags: bash

I have a file `/etc/singularity/singularity.conf` which has the following line:

```
mount dev = no
```

I want to automatically change `no` to `yes`. I can get this line:

```
grep "mount dev = no" /etc/singularity/singularity.conf
```

But how can I edit it to be `yes` in the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(mount dev = \)no/\1yes/' /etc/singularity/singularity.conf
```

The command above just writes the output to the console. If you want the changes to be applied to the file, you can pass the `-i` flag, i.e. `sed -i ...`

Answer (score -1):

You could do this using `sed` matching the line pattern:

```
sed '/mount dev =/s/no/yes/' /etc/singularity/singularity.conf
```

Make sure to add the `-i` parameter to actually overwrite the file.

Comment: The problem is that there are other places with `no` I want to keep them as `no`.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the line pattern